# using splheap in php 5.2

Tags: php, spl

Is there any way to use splheap in php 5.2? Ie. could I paste the classes somewhere? Specifically I want to use it to sort items in an iterator, I'm looking for the equivalent of usort() on an iterator.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use a heap? `ArrayIterator` is available (perhaps for you to extend as needed) for 5.2 and contains sorting functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SplHeap` *(as other classes provided by PHP itself)* is not coded in PHP.

It is actually coded in C -- as the rest of PHP itself -- and, as such, cannot just be *copy-pasted* to your project.

The only way you'd have of getting those classes into PHP 5.2 would be to :

- Get the sources of PHP 5.3
- Get the sources of PHP 5.2
- Do some kind of merge between those -- merging the definitions of `SplHead`, and all it can depend upon
- And compile your own version PHP 5.2 + those merges

This doesn't seem like quite an easy task ; and I would not recommend doing it : your PHP code would only be able to work with your own version of *"PHP 5.2+merges"*.

Instead, considering that PHP 5.2 has reached his end of life, it would be much wiser to upgrade to PHP 5.3.